# Como instalar o Android Studio em distribuições Linux?

Tags: java, android, linux

Eu sou novo como usuário linux, e instalei o `jdk 7` usando esse procedimento abaixo:

```
http://www.edivaldobrito.com.br/como-instalar-o-oracle-java/
```

Depois usei esse procedimento para instalar o android como mostra abaixo:

```
http://www.edivaldobrito.com.br/como-instalar-o-android-studio-ubuntu-14-04/
```

Depois fui no terminal console e digitei `studio` e nada aconteceu.

Verifiquei se o `java` está instalando com o comando `java-version`

Alguém pode me ajudar a instalar o **Android Studio**, pois estou tendo dificuldades.

Comment: Instalar o JDK 7 não ajuda em nada no Android Studio, para compilar aplicativos Android é preciso ter o JDK 6. Não precisa instalar um repositório de terceiro pra instalar o Android Studio, basta baixar os binários direto do site do Android: https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html.

Comment: @Wakim eu uso o jdk7 (openjdk, não da oracle) e aqui funciona perfeitamente, não acho que seja nescessário o JDK6, mas claro que por motivos de compatibilidade talvez seria melhor compilar com o jdk6.

Comment: Eu usei este tutorial como referencia para instalação do Android Studio no Ubuntu. Veja: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qfinKxwYYZs

Comment: Já tentou seguir o tutorial no arquivo: `Install-Linux-tar.txt` que vem dentro da pasta `android-studio` ?

Comment: linux e so o nome do kernel qual eo seu sistema operacional mais especificamente e qual a arquitetura 32 ou 64 ...

Comment: Lembrando que mesmo com o [tag:android-studio], você vai precisar do [Android NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk/index.html?hl=pt-br) caso pretenda compilar algo como o OpenSSL por exemplo. Eu prefiro usar o android studio fora do _linux_, deixando ele apenas na função de compilar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wladyband este é um repositório de terceiro, não sendo da Google, que pode ou não estar sendo atualizado. Idealmente baixe a versão mais nova no link https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html, descompacte e acessa a basta bin lá o arquivo studio.sh que você deve chamar por terminal da seguinte forma:

```
  ./android-studio/bin/studio.sh
```

a partir dai ele executará o android studio.

Answer (score 0):

Antes de instalar é necessário ter o JDK.

Para instalar o JDK:

1. baixe o aplicativo:
   https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
2. salve ele na sua pasta de downloads:  `~/Downloads/` e extraia, ficará assim: `~/Downloads/android-studio/`
3. agora abra o terminal do lin, e instale o JDK, digite: `sudo apt-get install openjdk-9-jdk`
4. instala as dependências: 
   `sudo apt-get intsall lib32z1 lib32ncruses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6`
5. Em seguida, navegue a até a pasta onde extraiu o Android Studio: `cd ~/Downloads/android-studio/` e pressione "Enter"
6. dê permissão para execução para o arquivo shell: `sudo chmod a+x ./bin/studio.sh`.
7. execute o arquivo, digite: `./bin/studio.sh`, depois que terminar, irá abrir uma tela para prosseguir.
8. Clique em "next", depois em "finish".

[**Aqui tem um passo-a-passo em vídeo**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jlPqaqlhBfM)

Answer (score 0):

Após instalar o Java, se for dist Debian, instale os repositórios e o Android Studio com os comandos abaixo no terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:paolorotolo/android-studio  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install android-studio
```